# how to get response 200 instead of response 400 and 304 in python

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, response

I have list of Urls that is in file.txt that are online without problem
I am going to get response 200 whole of them but it just can get 20 percent of them response 200
How can I get it correctly?

I try divide it to 4 thread to get response in smaller time and I set header and get request of urls.

```
import threading
import requests
import eventlet

def foo():
    data = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9B179 Safari/7534.48.3'}
    with open('c.txt', 'r') as f:
        line = f.readlines()
    for l in line[0:50]:
        with eventlet.Timeout(2):
            try:
                r = requests.get(l,headers=data,timeout= 2)
                print(r,t.getName())
               
            except:
                pass
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t = threading.Thread(target = foo, name="Siyamak" )
    t.start()

def bar():
    data = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9B179 Safari/7534.48.3'}
    with open('c.txt', 'r') as f:
        line = f.readlines()
    for l in line[50:100]:
        with eventlet.Timeout(2):
            try:
                r = requests.get(l,headers=data,timeout= 2)
                print(r,t2.getName())
            except:
                pass
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t2 = threading.Thread(target = bar,name="diyana")
    t2.start()
```

Comment: Do all the urls return 200 if done one at a time? If so, maybe trying spacing them out with a pause or Timer threads.

Comment: No. But all of url is true while i click on the link and i can see the website